# Update or use the latest version of kube-prometheus-stack?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, kube-prometheus-stack

Question is: we have some version of kube-prometheus-stack (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack) for example version 20.0.0. I want to install just version 40.0.0. Based on docs I should install crd's by using kubectl apply -f somecrd. Can I just install version 40.0.0 which is just working and has all of those crd's alteady installed?

Thanks

- Update from 20.0.0 to 24.0.0 - always problems with crd
- I just want the latest version of kube-prometheus-stack

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the [docs](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack#from-39-x-to-40-x), if you want to upgrade your version of kube-stack-prometheus to 40.0.0, you will need to upgrade the crds using the following commands, and remove the daemonset before upgrading the kube-prometheus-stack chart:

```
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.59.1/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagerconfigs.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.59.1/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_alertmanagers.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.59.1/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_podmonitors.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.59.1/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_probes.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.59.1/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_prometheuses.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.59.1/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_prometheusrules.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.59.1/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_servicemonitors.yaml
kubectl apply --server-side -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/v0.59.1/example/prometheus-operator-crd/monitoring.coreos.com_thanosrulers.yaml
```

It isn't recommended to run such a big upgrade (20.0.0 -> 40.0.0), as there may be numerous changes in the helm charts default values.yaml so if you just want the latest version, you may consider uninstalling the helm chart and deleting all the crds before reinstalling the updated version.